# SQLite Multiple Insert with Query Syntax Error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm attempting to insert multiple rows into an SQLite DB with python. I've got three tables:

UniversityA:

- id
- course_name
- course_code
- course_prefix

UniversityB:

- id
- course_name
- course_code
- course_prefix

CourseMap:

- universityA_id (references id from universityA)
- universityB_id (references id from universityB)
- is_flagged (boolean 0/1)

I can add a single record to the CourseMap table easily with this syntax:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO CourseMap (universityA_id, universityB_id, is_flagged) VALUES ( (SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"), (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), 0)')
```

But when I try to incorporate this statement into a list to execute multiple inserts using `executemany()`, I get a syntax error:

```
equivs = [
    ((SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"), (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), 0),
    ((SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"), (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), 0),
    ((SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"), (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), 0)
]

# Fill the table
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO courseMap (universityA_id, universityB_id, is_flagged) VALUES (?,?,?)', equivs)
```

The error I'm getting is "syntax error: invalid syntax", with the caret positioned right before the boolean `is_flagged` value on the first insert.

Am I missing something in the multiple insert syntax on `executemany()`? My SQLite 3 version is 3.10.0.

Comment: Are the select statements in your `equivs` declaration supposed to be strings?

Comment: My thinking was that they shouldn't be since the `INSERT` statement they'll be plugged into is a string...do you mean the items in `equivs` should be in quotes?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how you didn't get a syntax error on *that* before it even got to the `executemany` statement.

Comment: To clarify, there should be quotes (single quotes, since you have double quotes in the select) before each `SELECT` and after each `"AERO"` and `"ARCH"`.

Comment: Actually, my mistake. It looks like they need to be outside the parentheses.

Comment: Looks like adding single quotes either inside or outside the parentheses adds the entire SQL statement into the DB as a string.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. In this case since the subqueries are static and not based on user input, it should be safe to just format them into the query instead of doing parameter substitution.

Comment: How would I format the subqueries to avoid them being added into the DB as strings?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a DDL/DML SQL statement (i.e., `SELECT` statement) as a parameter. In fact, that is the **very reason** for parameterization! Recall the [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) injection issue. Parameters are designed to receive a single binded value per executed call.

For your needs, consider one executed statement of a union cross join which you can do by comma separated `SELECT` statements or explicit [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-cross-join/). Below assumes each query `SELECT` returns only one *id* value) else you will append cartesian cross products.

```sql
INSERT INTO CourseMap (universityA_id, universityB_id, is_flagged) 

SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"), 
   (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), (SELECT 0)

UNION ALL 

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"), 
    (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), (SELECT 0)

UNION ALL 

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=301 AND course_prefix="AERO"),  
    (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=101 AND course_prefix="ARCH"), (SELECT 0)
```

*Aside - reconsider this schema as duplicate structured tables like the two University ones strays from best practices as both tables can be appended into one with an indicator field ('A' or 'B') for efficient storage, querying, and scaling.*

Comment: I'm confused as to why I would be able to insert a single row with a subquery inside the INSERT, but couldn't do the same with multiple rows.

Comment: Your first attempt that ran successfully executed an entire SQL statement without any parameters as this solution shows. Your failed attempt tried to pass an SQL statements as a parameter. Plus, parameters are not evaluated on their own but binded to a prepared statement. Prepare your SQL statement then pass values as list of tuples as @CL. shows or all at once with union cross join like here.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can use multiple tuples in the VALUES clause; this requires to write the subqueries multiple times:

```sql
INSERT INTO CourseMap (universityA_id, universityB_id, is_flagged)
VALUES ( (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...), 0),
       ( (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...), 0),
       ( (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...), 0);
```

Python's `executemany()` execute the *same* statement multiple times with different parameter values. So the only thing you can change are the actual values used in the subqueries:

```
args = [ (301, "AERO", 101, "ARCH"), (...) ]
db.executemany("""INSERT INTO CourseMap (universityA_id, universityB_id, is_flagged)
                  VALUES ( (SELECT id from universityA WHERE course_code=? AND course_prefix=?),
                           (SELECT id from universityB WHERE course_code=? AND course_prefix=?),
                          0)""", args)
```

If that is not what you want to change, you have to execute the subqueries separately, and give their results to `executemany`.